# selecciones limitidas y dependientes entre dos grupos de checkbox

Tags: php, html

Quisiera saber cómo condicionar la selección de elementos en grupo de checkbox, si en otro grupo algun elemento fue seleccionado

Poseo dos checkbox:

un primer checkbox llamado `comida_fuerte`:

- Pescado
- Pollo
- Carne

Y otro checkbox llamado `comida_sopa`:

- res
- gallina
- pollo

Entonces quisiera hacer que:

- Solo se puedan tomar máximo dos opciones de cada grupo de checkbox,
  no se si debe cambiar el name de cada checkbox o dejarlo asi.
- Solo se pueda marcar elementos de un grupo de checkbox, ya sea
  `comida_fuerte` o `comida_sopa`, si selecciono algun elemento de `comida_fuerte` automáticamente se bloquee `comida_sopa` y viceversa si selecciona algún elemento de `comida_sopa` se bloquee `comida_fuerte`

Este es el codigo de ejemplo

```
<html>
NOTA:
*Solo es posible seleccionar dos elementos(como maximo) de algún grupo
de opciones, ya sea de comida fuerte o de sopas.
*Solo se puede seleccionar elementos de un grupo en particular, es
decir, si selecciona comida fuerte solo podrá tomar elementos de dicho
grupo y por el contrario si selecciona sopas, solo podra tomar sopas.

Elija su comida fuerte
<input type="checkbox" name="comida_fuerte" value="pollo">
<input type="checkbox" name="comida_fuerte" value="carne">
<input type="checkbox" name="comida_fuerte" value="pescado">

Elija su sopa
<input type="checkbox" name="comida_sopa" value="res">
<input type="checkbox" name="comida_sopa" value="gallina">
<input type="checkbox" name="comida_sopa" value="pollo">
```

Me comentaron que se podia hacer con un select que al activar
seleccionar `comida_fuerte` o `comida_sopa` te desplegara los checkbox
pero no se cómo hacerlo

CODIGO FINAL

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var allFoods = document.querySelectorAll(
  'input[name="comida_fuerte"],'+
  'input[name="comida_sopa"]'
);

[].forEach.call(allFoods, function (food) {
  food.addEventListener('change', onFoodSelected);
});

/**
 * Se ejecuta cuando se cambia el valor
 * de 'checked' de cada checkbox. Solo
 * se admiten dos checkboxes seleccionados
 */
function onFoodSelected (e) {
  var name = e.target.getAttribute('name');
  var selected = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');

  if (selected.length === 0) {
    [].forEach.call(allFoods, function (food) {
        food.disabled = false;
    }); 
  } else if (selected.length <= 2) {
    disableAltFood(name);
  } else if (selected.length > 2) {
    e.target.checked = false;
  }
}

/**
 * Desactiva el grupo de checkbox
 * de comidas alternativas.
 *
 * @param {string} name Tipo de comida
 */
function disableAltFood (name) {
  var discriminator = 'comida_';
  discriminator += name.indexOf('fuerte') < 0 ? 'fuerte' : 'sopa';
  var foods = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="' + discriminator + '"]');
  [].forEach.call(foods, function (food) {
    food.disabled = true;
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<form action="procesar.php" method="post">
<label for="name"> nombre </label>  <br/>
<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="ingrese su nombre"*>
 <br/>

<label for="codigo"> codigo </label>  <br/>
<input type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="ingrese su nombre"*>
<br/>
Elija su comida fuerte
<?php

$registros= mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM comida_fuerte");
while($comida = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='comida_fuerte' value='".$comida["id_comida_fuerte"]."'>".$comida["desc_comida_fuerte"];
}

?>

<br/>

Elija su sopa
<?php

$registros2= mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM comida_sopa");
while($comida2 = mysqli_fetch_array($registros2)){
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='comida_sopa' value='".$comida2["id_comida_sopa"]."'>".$comida2["desc_comida_sopa"];
}

?>
<br/>

<input type="submit" value="registrar"*>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes usar el evento [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) de los checkboxes y el atributo [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/disabled).

**Ejemplo**

```js
var allFoods = document.querySelectorAll(
  'input[name="comida_fuerte"],'+
  'input[name="comida_sopa"]'
);

[].forEach.call(allFoods, function (food) {
  food.addEventListener('change', onFoodSelected);
});

/**
 * Se ejecuta cuando se cambia el valor
 * de 'checked' de cada checkbox. Solo
 * se admiten dos checkboxes seleccionados
 */
function onFoodSelected (e) {
  var name = e.target.getAttribute('name');
  var selected = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
  
  if (selected.length === 0) {
    [].forEach.call(allFoods, function (food) {
     food.disabled = false;
    }); 
  } else if (selected.length <= 2) {
   disableAltFood(name);
  } else if (selected.length > 2) {
    e.target.checked = false;
  }
}

/**
 * Desactiva el grupo de checkbox
 * de comidas alternativas.
 *
 * @param {string} name Tipo de comida
 */
function disableAltFood (name) {
  var discriminator = 'comida_';
  discriminator += name.indexOf('fuerte') < 0 ? 'fuerte' : 'sopa';
  var foods = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="' + discriminator + '"]');
  [].forEach.call(foods, function (food) {
    food.disabled = true;
  });
}
```

```html
Elija su comida fuerte
<input type="checkbox" name="comida_fuerte" value="pollo">
<input type="checkbox" name="comida_fuerte" value="carne">
<input type="checkbox" name="comida_fuerte" value="pescado">
<br/>
Elija su sopa
<input type="checkbox" name="comida_sopa" value="res">
<input type="checkbox" name="comida_sopa" value="gallina">
<input type="checkbox" name="comida_sopa" value="pollo">
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53198/discussion-on-answer-by-guzgarcia-selecciones-limitidas-y-dependientes-entre-dos).